# Search Database via Google Custom Search? Attached Google CSE to (SQL/NoSQL) Database for website?

Tags: sql, database, search, google-search-api, nosql

**TOPIC - Google Search Engine / Custom Search - with Database**

**References**

Search for **"Google Search Engine"** and [**"Google Custom Search"**](https://developers.google.com/custom-search)
(New to StackOverflow; just joined the other day.**I'm limited to 2 links** I can post right now).

**NOTE:** 
I have **not** YET decided/committed to **any specific coding language, framework, etc.** Not until I figure out how to accomplish my question (below).

**BACKGROUND INFO**

What I'm trying to do (for now) is **add a "search-box/ search engine"** to a **simple website** I'm building out. Before I get too far into it (planning ahead) I would like to use Google CSE if all possible (which can do A LOT of things and works well). However, I will have a database *(not sure on type YET. Will depend on what my options and I can do with CSE)* of "items" that I want to be able to quickly search (in the search-box) i.e. like Amazon.com.

**QUESTION:**

Is there any way at all, to use **Google Custom Search** and or **Custom Search API** to search/attach a database (SQL, NoSQL, or others)? I would **HIGHLY prefer** being able to do all of this in Google Cloud Platform, and use one of their [storage/database products](https://cloud.google.com/products/storage/).

Answer (score 2):

If I get what you try to do, Google CSE is enough.

From the google doc you linked :

### [#Defining a Custom Search Engine in Control Panel](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/creatingcse#defining_a_custom_search_engine_in_control_panel)

> In the Sites to search section, add the pages you want to include in
> your search engine. You can include any sites you want, not just the
> sites you own. You can include whole site URLs or individual pages
> URLs. You can also use URL patterns.

### [#Enabling Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/autocomplete)

> [...]you can enable or disable autocomplete feature using
> enableAutoComplete attribute.

---

For the *`Is there any way at all [..] to search a database`*, I'll said not directly, but it's not a big problem.

Google CSE work on "indexable web pages", so it'll not work again a raw DB, restricted internet, or custom network not under `http(s)://`.

But in your case, if you make a DB, I suppose you'll have to make web page to display the data you store inside to your users ? (like products pages on Amazon)

If yes, then you'll run Google CSE again these pages by adding your `http://[server ip]` or `http://[domain name]` in the white list.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, custom search won't guarantee all your content will be indexed.

You probably want to try exporting a full sitemap.xml, a RSS feed and if the custom search results from either of these won't satisfy you, you will probably want to look at the google search appliance product.

There's also http://sphinxsearch.com/ by the way.